# How do I get history information who push new modify in Google Cloud Repositories?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, git-history

I'm building a web app to receive a message when I pushed my newly modified code to Google Cloud Repositories.

I tried to use Google PubSub service to help me to get some information when push event activities, but I still cannot get information about *who* commits new code.

I tried to visit API of the Google Cloud Repositories, but I still can't get any info about the commit description.

How can I get the commit description in my situation?

Comment: Create an event in Stackdriver logging. The identity is one of the fields.

Comment: Hi, @JohnHanley, thanks your responses but I tried to visit the Stackdriver logging document and I don't have any idea where can I see what I want to know.

Could you give me more news for what about you said.

Thanks so much.

Comment: In Stackdriver Logging, select "Cloud Source Repository". Make sure you are in the same project.

Comment: Hi @JohnHanley.
Thank you so much, I found what you said already but still not help me to work.

Because I want to get the "message" of when people executed the git command with commit and push to Google Cloud Repositories.

It's really appreciate for your response.